# How do I add additional series to a Excel Chart using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

[image]I am trying to add an additional data series to the chart this shows CPU threshold, I can get the range and create the graph with out the threshold on it, but I don't know how to add the threshold value to the chart.
do I need to create another chart object? can I use the existing and just add teh new range in?

[image: Threshold values]

How are you creating the chart? -- see code below.
Is this chart already created in the excel file, and you want to modify the chart in the excel file? yes the chart is already in a Excel file.

Excel.ChartObjects sCPUChart;
            Excel.ChartObject sCPUChartObjects;

```
        sCPUChart = sDBSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        sCPUChartObjects = sCPUChart.Add(49, 15, 360, 215);

        Excel.Chart sChartCPU;

        sChartCPU = sCPUChartObjects.Chart;
        sChartCPU.SetSourceData(cpuChartRange, Missing.Value);
        sChartCPU.ChartWizard(Source: cpuChartRange, Gallery: Excel.XlChartType.xlLine, Format: 2, HasLegend: true);
        sChartCPU.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, sDBSheet.Name);

        //CPU Chart Axis
        Excel.Axis xSChartCPUAxis;
        xSChartCPUAxis = sChartCPU.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);


        Excel.Axis ySChartCPUAxis;
        ySChartCPUAxis = syChartCPU.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        ySChartCPUAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
        ySChartCPUAxis.MaximumScaleIsAuto = true;

        //Set Summary CPU Series
        Excel.Series sCPUSeries = sChartCPU.SeriesCollection(1);
        sCPUSeries.Name = "CPU";


//-------
// this is where I am having my issue
//I don't know how to add the threshold line to the graph with the existing graph being displayed

        //sChartCPU.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary, true);
        //summaryChartCPU.SetSourceData(summaryMemThreshold, Type.Missing); -- things break
        //-------
I have now done the following:


   Excel.SeriesCollection threshold = sChartCPU.sseriesCollection();
   Excel.Series line = threshold.NewSeries();
   line.Formula = "=SERIES(Summ!$D$54,Summ!$C$55:$C$56,Summ!$D$55:$D$56)";
   line.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xLScatterLinesNoMarkers;


when the threshold line is created I have the following
```

[image: with new series]

the values I have in cells D54 - threshold

```
  C55 = 0
  C56 = 1
  D55 = 75
  D56 = 75
```

I don't know how to remove the 2 additional axis that appear in chart
If I comment out the line.ChartType, then the axis is correct but I only get one threshold data point ?? I don't understand why.

Comment: How are you creating the chart? Is this chart already created in the excel file, and you want to modify the chart in the excel file?

Answer (score 4):

```
var series = (SeriesCollection) yourChart.SeriesCollection();
var line = series.NewSeries();

line.Name = "CPU Threshhold";
//line.Values = ...;
//line.XValues = ...;

//formatting
```

Comment: So I tried this, 'Excel.SeriesCollection threshold = sChartCPU.SeriesCollection(); Excel Series line = threshold.NewSeries(); line.values = "75,75";' however I get errors on line.values

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found to the OP's question of how to remove the secondary axes:

```
Excel.SeriesCollection threshold = sChartCPU.sseriesCollection();
Excel.Series line = threshold.NewSeries();

// line.Formula = "=SERIES(Summ!$D$54,Summ!$C$55:$C$56,Summ!$D$55:$D$56)";
// instead of setting the Formula, I set the series values
line.Values = "='Summ!'$D$55:$D$56";
line.XValues = "='Summ!'$C$55:$C$56";

line.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers;


// creates Axis objects for the secondary axes
Excel.Axis YAxis2 = (Excel.Axis)sChartCPU.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);
Excel.Axis XAxis2 = (Excel.Axis)sChartCPU.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);

// remove the major and minor tick marks from the secondary (top) x-axis
XAxis2.MajorTickMark = Excel.XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;
XAxis2.MinorTickMark = Excel.XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;

// change the secondary x-axis max range to 1.0 so the bar will go all the way to the right side
XAxis2.MaximumScale = 1.0;

// delete the secondary x-axis labels 
XAxis2.TickLabels.Delete();

// I chose to delete the secondary y-axis so the line would graph on the primary axis scale
YAxis2.Delete();
```